# Testing in according to BDD

Tags: java, cucumber, bdd

I need to make test with Cucumber based on the following conditions:

1. I need to calculate number of days from inputed date to today;
2. I need to put restriction that introduced date are not after today (for example 2023-11-01)
3. I need to check if Scenarios in from feature file are satisfied;

Bellow you could find scenarios and code:

days_calculator.feature:
Feature: determine how many days are from birthday in according to entered date.

```
  Scenario: entered date is before today
    Given I enter the date <2023-01-01>
    When I want to calculate based on today
    Then the result should be 270

  Scenario: entered date is after today
    Given I enter the date <2024-01-01>
    When I want to calculate based on today
    Then the result should be 0
```

Stepdefinitions.java:

```
package agecalculator_example;

import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import java.util.Date;

public class StepDefinition {
    int actual;
    @Given("I enter the date <{int}{int}{int}>")
    public void iEnterTheDate(int arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {

    }

    @When("I want to calculate based on today")
    public void i_want_to_calculate_based_on_today() {
        actual = calculator.
    }

    @Then("the result should be {int}")
    public void the_result_should_be(Integer expected) {
        if (actual != expected) {
            throw new AssertionError("Assertion is not equal with expected.");
        }

    }
}
```

Fuctionality calculator.java:

```
package agecalculator_example;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class calculator {
    LocalDate start = LocalDate.parse("2023-01-01");
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.parse("2023-09-28");
    long DiffinDays;

    {
        DiffinDays = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(start, end);
        System.out.println(DiffinDays);
    }
}
```

Please help to finalize this test. I'm beginner in Java and Cucumber testing

Comment: Your test looks fine. You probably want a method in your Calculator class to do the calculation, which takes the dates as arguments; rather than hard-coding them in your class the way you have. So your call in your `I want to calculate...` step will be something like `calculator.calculateDoB(start, end)`. I would also pick up the whole date from the steps if you can, and use a date parser to turn it into something meaningful.